# Wheelchair accessibility in Directions API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I'd like to retrieve directions for wheelchair-bound users, allowing me to provide wheelchair accessible routes. My Google Maps app allows this, but there's nothing about it in the API documentation.
Does the Directions API support this? If not, how do Google Maps do it?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this feature is not available in Google Maps API. If you would like this feature to be added, you may file a Feature Request in our public [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) to include this feature in the Directions API.

Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development.[5] It is available outside of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to collaborate with Google teams on specific projects. You can learn more here [1].

[1] https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/